# Orthogonal in the B Norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

> If you have two generalized
>   eigenvectors $\varphi_1 , \varphi_2$
>   (with different eigenvalues) of a
>   matrix **A**, then they will be
>   orthogonal in the **B** norm.

In this context, I do not understand what is meant by the "**B** norm" where **B** is a matrix of the same dimensions as **A**. What does it mean to be orthogonal in another matrices' norm?

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this? It is probably easier to figure it out in context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $A \varphi_i = \lambda_i B \varphi_i$.  I'm assuming $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, with $B$ positive definite.  Then
$\lambda_1 \varphi_1^T B \varphi_2 = \varphi_1^T A \varphi_2 = \lambda_2 \varphi_1^T B \varphi_2$ with $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$, so $\varphi_1^T B \varphi_2 = 0$.  This says that $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are orthogonal in the inner product $(u,v) = u^T B v$ corresponding to the matrix $B$, which might be abbreviated as "in the $B$ norm".

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm trying to parse your response because I'm a novice in Linear Algebra.

Comment: When you say that, "$\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are orthogonal in the inner product $(u,v)=u^TBv$", are $u,v$ just $\varphi_1 , \varphi_2$?

Comment: In the definition of the inner product, $u$ and $v$ are any vectors in the vector space.  You are using this definition with $u = \varphi_1$, $v = \varphi_2$.